# Program a Changing Daily Message

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

How would I go about programming a daily message on my site that changes daily? I'm thinking of preloading all the messages in a MySQL database.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

I've tried

```
$msg_sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."quotes ORDER BY rand(curdate()) LIMIT 3";
$msg_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $msg_sql));
```

But this only grabs the first MySQL result?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/daily-random-quotes.htm

Comment: There are a million ways to do that.. You need to give us something to get started with

Comment: Thanks, I just edited with the MySQL problem I'm running into..

Comment: your query seems a bit weird to say the least. From what I've seen above, if I were you, I'd honestly skip relying on mysql alltogether. Using a LIMIT 3 and hoping to get just 1 result, and that ORDER BY clause are something telling me mysql might not be the best tool for you. At least without getting a bit deeper into it. How about my idea below? Doesn't it solve your issue without bothering a DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a real message changing daily, you actually don't need to rely on a database or anything fancy. A simple idea might be to create a directory (say /var/www/motds) and populate it with files named YYYY-MM-DD.txt (where YYYY is a 4 digit year number, MM is a two digit month number and DD is a 2 digit day number).

Then, the only thing you need to do in order to display your motd is:

> ```
> $filename = '/var/www/motds/'.date("Y-m-d").'.txt';
> if (file_exists($filename)) {
>     echo file_get_contents($filename);
> }
> ```

If you want your daily messages to be taken from a pool of entries (that you can pre-load), you might do something as follows:

```
$files = scandir('/var/www/motds'); // put files into an array
$messagecount = count($files) - 2;  // .. and . shall not be considered
$day = date("z");  // what day do we have today? 
echo file_get_contents('/var/www/motds/' . $files[($day % $messagecount) + 2]);
```

Comment: would there be a way to put all the quotes in one text file?

Comment: there'd many ways.. one could be to use an ini file, and then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php to get the quote you need. Might not be the best solution, but could work for you. Or you could put one quote per line and use http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to get this done.  You list PHP in your tags, so maybe check here:

[PHP Script: Quote of the Day](http://blazonry.com/php/quoteoftheday.php)

or maybe [here](http://px.sklar.com/code.html/id=789)